# org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock exception

Tags: selenium

I am using ivy for dependency management. i am getting the following exception now,suddenly this exception came but  before it was working fine..

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:88)
    at com.ensarm.crawler.web.browser.FirefoxBrowser.initialize(FirefoxBrowser.java:296)
    at com.ensarm.crawler.navigator.IpProxyNavigator.initialize(IpProxyNavigator.java:46)
    at com.ensarm.crawler.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:23)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firefox driver for selenium doesn't have the [ephemeral socket issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ScalingWebDriver) fixed, which often causes the stack trace above. There may be some test cases being run by ivy which if you turn off would solve this particular issue.